# How do I add my classes to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, random, arraylist, paintcomponent

I'm very new to Java and programming in general and I'm having a bit of trouble with my homework assignment. 
We're supposed to give a variation of 4 different shapes, 10 shape in each picture with variation of at least 20, also variation of at least 20 different colors and variation of position.

I've made classes for each of my 5 shapes. But I somehow don't know how to add them to my ArrayList randomShape so that they can be called in the paintComponent section. 
Also I'm having trouble coming up with the code the positions :(

Its a bit frustrating that I've hit a road block of thoughts.

Thank you for any help/advice you give me 
It's very much appreciated

Here is my code that I have so far

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cara extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
Random random = new Random();

public static final int MAX_AMOUNT_OF_SHAPES = 50,AMOUNT_OF_DISTINCT_SHAPES=5,         AMOUNT_OF_DISTINCT_COLORS = 20, SIZE_MAX_X_COORDINATE = 400, SIZE_MAX_Y_COORDINATE = 300;;
public static ArrayList<RandomShape> randomShape = new ArrayList<RandomShape>();

int x = 0;
int xMax = 400;
int y = 0;
int yMax = 300;
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
int arcWidth = 0;
int arcHeight = 0;

int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
int G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
int B = (int)(Math.random()*256);
Color randomColor = new Color(R,G,B);

public Cara(){
setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400,300));
}

abstract class RandomShape {
protected Color color;
protected int x,y;

abstract void draw(Graphics g);
}

public class Circle extends RandomShape{

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {
  g.drawOval(x,y,width,width);
  g.fillOval(x,y,width,width);
  g.setColor(randomColor);
}
//constructor for random position
Circle (){
  for ( int x; x < xMax; x++){
  }
  for ( int y; y < yMax; y++){
  }
}
}

public class Rectangle extends RandomShape{
@Override
public void draw( Graphics g){
  g.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
  g.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
  g.setColor(randomColor);
}
//constructor for random position
}

public class RoundRectangle extends RandomShape{
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
  g.drawRoundRect(x,y,width,height,arcWidth,arcHeight);
  g.fillRoundRect(x,y,width,height,arcWidth,arcHeight);
  g.setColor(randomColor);
}
//constructor for random position
}

public class Oval extends RandomShape{
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
  g.drawOval(x,y,width,height);
  g.fillOval(x,y,width,height); 
  g.setColor(randomColor);
}
//constructor for position
}

public class Square extends RandomShape{
Square square = new Square();
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
  g.drawRect(x,y,width,width); //because is a rectangle with sides of equal size
  g.fillRect(x,y,width,width);
  g.setColor(randomColor);
}
//constructor for position 
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
//clear the background
super.paintComponent(g);
//draw all shapes 
for ( RandomShape rs: randomShape){
rs.draw(g);
} 
}


public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
regenerate();
repaint();
}

private void regenerate() {
//clear the shapes list 
randomShape.clear();

// create random shapes
RandomShape shape = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10 + random.nextInt(MAX_AMOUNT_OF_SHAPES); i++){
  int randomInt = random.nextInt(AMOUNT_OF_DISTINCT_SHAPES);

  switch (randomInt) {
    case 0: shape = new Oval(400,300);
    break;
    case 1: shape = new Circle(400,300);
    break;
    case 2: shape = new Rectangle(400,300);
    break;
    case 3: shape = new Square(400,300);
    break;
    case 4: shape = new RoundRectangle(400,300);
    break;
  } 
}

//random position
RandomShape position = null;
for (int i = 0; i < (MAX_SIZE_X_COORDINATE*MAX_SIZE_Y_COORDINATE) ; i++){
  int randomIntpos = random.nextInt();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
final Cara cara = new Cara();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Computer Assisted Random Artist");
    JButton button = new JButton("regenerate");
    button.addActionListener(cara);
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    cara.regenerate();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
});
}
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask for code review. If you have a specific problem, we can help you. We can't help with _road block of thoughts_.

Comment: `randomShape.add(..)` .... maybe?

Comment: I tried that already but every time I do randomShape.add(circle); for example it gives me an error :(

Comment: Have you already created the new instance of circle first? randomShape.add(new Circle());

Comment: Probably not, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Check above for doing it anonymously, or you can do Circle circle = new Circle(); any arguments need to go in the parens for your new Circle object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I wasn't specifically asking for code review. I've stated the specific problems I'm having trouble with. And mentioning hitting a road block of thoughts is just me being elaborate because I talk a lot, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: What you've done is dump a bunch (mostly irrelevant) code and asked for help, but haven't been specific. You speak of errors but don't provide them. It's like you are expecting us to give you the code solution for all your problems. Don't. Go read the FAQ and come back and improve your question with relevant details.

Comment: @sage88 okay thank you, that seems to solve that issue. Just to make sure I had to put randomShape.add(...); in the super.paintComponent(g) section right?

Comment: I have no idea where it should go. That is entirely dependent on your program's logic. I don't think that sounds like a reasonable place to put it. Your indentation is such that it's very difficult to tell where anything should go.

Comment: @sage88 I'm supposed to draw all the shapes in the super.paintComponent(g). so thats why I think they should do there, but of course I could be wrong

Comment: Just because you draw them all with the paintComponent method doesn't mean that's the best place to add them. You're probably better off adding them where you've created the randomShape ArrayList, though in this case it's working where you added them because randomShape is a public instance variable (which is not good design) and you could add to it from anywhere, even other classes.

Comment: @sage88 Can you explain to me why if I put them in the class where the ArrayList is created that it gives me a lot of extra errors whereas if i put them in the paintComponent class it seems to be okay?

Comment: They should be added in the Cara class' constructor as I have shown below. You have probably put them outside the constructor, so that's why you're throwing errors. When you initialize a class you should do your object creation in the constructor whenever possible. I have shown an example of this below.

Comment: @sage88 It's giving me errors now in my switch statement "cannot find symbol, symbol constructor RoundRectangle(int, int) . What am I doing wrong here, before it didn't give me errors on my switch statement

Comment: Alright, after reading through some of your code it looks like you should be adding objects to your randomShape array in the switch statement, not in the constructor since that's where you're actually creating your random shapes and it's also where you've already instantiated random shapes and then done nothing with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Cara extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static ArrayList<RandomShape> randomShape;

    public Cara() {
        randomShape = new ArrayList<RandomShape>();
    }
}

private void regenerate() {
    //clear the shapes list 
    randomShape.clear();

    // create random shapes
    RandomShape shape = null;
    int randomInt;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 + random.nextInt(MAX_AMOUNT_OF_SHAPES); i++) {
        randomInt = random.nextInt(AMOUNT_OF_DISTINCT_SHAPES);

        switch (randomInt) {
            case 0: 
                shape = new Oval(400,300);
                break;
            case 1: 
                shape = new Circle(400,300);
                break;
            case 2: 
                shape = new Rectangle(400,300);
                break;
            case 3: 
                shape = new Square(400,300);
                break;
            case 4: 
                shape = new RoundRectangle(400,300);
                break;
        } 
        randomShape.add(shape);
    }

    //random position
    RandomShape position = null;
    int randomIntpos;
    for (int i = 0; i < (MAX_SIZE_X_COORDINATE*MAX_SIZE_Y_COORDINATE) ; i++){
        randomIntpos = random.nextInt();
    }
}

public class RoundRectangle extends RandomShape {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    //constructor for random position
    public RoundRectangle(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawRoundRect(x,y,width,height,arcWidth,arcHeight);
        g.fillRoundRect(x,y,width,height,arcWidth,arcHeight);
        g.setColor(randomColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to continue programming in Java please read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @user2855331 see update above. Keep in mind that your random position code as it stands is totally non-functional and I'm not fixing it for you.

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me the same errors in the switch statement

Comment: yes I know, it isn't which is why I already removed it but that was just after posting it and I forgot to edit it, sorry

Comment: You are passing in arguments to classes that don't have constructors. Like I said before, READ THE ABOVE LINK! You don't know how to use constructors and you're making calls to make new objects with arguments without realizing where those arguments are trying to go. I gave you sort of an example updated above, but really read that tutorial and a lot will become clear. PS: before it didn't give you errors on your switch statement because it was failing before it got that far.

Comment: Alrighty, well thank you for all the help. Really appreciate it, sorry for any frustration my scrubbiness caused. Have a nice day/night wherever you are from :)